# LightningMessageChannel error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service

I'm trying to do some trainning for LWC using LMS, but when I push my source I get below error

```
org.auraframework.throwable.AuraRuntimeException: Unable to retrieve metadata for descriptor: markup://c:__LightningMessageChannel__Account_Selected_c
```

My Account_Selected.messageChannel-meta.xml file is under messageChannels folder and already depolyed to org.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<masterLabel>AccountSelected</masterLabel>
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<description>Message Channel to pass Account Selected</description>
<lightningMessageFields>
<fieldName>recodeId</fieldName>
<description>This is the record Id that changed</description>
</lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

My publisher component and subscriber component have

```
import ACCOUNT_SELECTED_CHANNEL from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Account_Selected_c';
```

then when I push the source to org, I get the error.
Can someone help me to figure out how I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `__c`, not `_c`.

```
import ACCOUNT_SELECTED_CHANNEL from '@salesforce/messageChannel/Account_Selected__c';
```

Comment: Thank you! yes that's right, should be __c